# Find the equation of the sine function graphed below.

Tags: calculus

Find the equation of the sine function graphed below.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Write a cosine function for the graph below. Assume the least possible phase shift.[image]

Comment: I'am trying to learn this concept and the explanation on how to do this was no help at all... If you could explain how to do this or show a solution it would be appreciated thanks Tony.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Your answer should be of the form $f(x)=A \sin (kx+\phi)$.  What is the amplitude of a sine wave before you multiply it by $A$?  What is the wavelength before you multiply $x$ by $k$?  Where does it pass through $0$?

Comment: There is a total of 8 periods?

Comment: the wave length is 3pi/4 roughly if I'am correct it passes through 0 at -2 on the y axis.

Comment: @user73122:  A period of $\frac {3\pi}4$ is correct for the second.  The second is offset from zero, so there will be an addition of a constant.  What $y$ value is halfway between the peak and the valley?

Comment: I believe it would be 2? but i'am not to sure.

Comment: @user73122:  To my eye, the peak is $2$ and the valley is $-6$, so the average is $-2$.  Your answer to the second should then look like $f(x)=A\cos (kx+ \phi) -2$.  A wavelength has to take the argument through $2\pi$, so choose $k$ to make that happen.  If you remember that $\cos x$ is at its maximum at $x=0$ you should be able to find $\phi$

Comment: what about number 1 .. :) ?

Comment: @user73122:  your comments seemed to address figure 2, so I thought you understood figure 1.  The approach is the same. Where are you having difficulty?